# Is there a way to find where the internal classes are moved

Tags: eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

We are migrating our application from Eclipse Indigo to Photon and I need help find a solution or alternate for a particular class which is present in Indigo but not in Photon.

The class we are trying to figure out is `org.eclipse.ui.internal.navigator.AdaptabilityUtility`.
Since it is an Internal class it is not available. But we had no luck finding an alternate.

Only one function of the class is used :

```java
IAdaptable openable = (IAdaptable) AdaptabilityUtility.getAdapter(
        selection.getFirstElement(), IResource.class);
```

If someone knows an alternative method which can be used here, it will be a great help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Eclipse internals were completely rewritten for Eclipse 4 so in general there may not be exact alternatives for internal classes which were never part of the official API.

However for AdaptabilityUtility it looks like the current `org.eclipse.core.runtime.Adapters` class should work:

```java
IResource resource = Adapters.adapt(selection.getFirstElement(), IResource.class);
```

`Adapters.adapt` uses generics so casts are not needed. Adapters is not internal so it is an official API.